# Tried Linear Regression But Reshape Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to put out a linear regression but am getting this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2246 into shape (2,2246)
```

and

```
C:\Users\Brian\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: FutureWarning: reshape is deprecated and will raise in a subsequent release. Please use .values.reshape(...) instead
```

This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\GOOGTICKER.CSV')
df
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'])
grouped= df.groupby([times.year]).mean()
from sklearn import linear_model
x_val= times
y_val= df['GOOGL']
body_reg =linear_model.LinearRegression()
body_reg.fit(x_val, y_val)
```

I have imported numpy as py and have tried reshaping, but I still get an error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't give information about what is inside CSV file, neither DataFrame shape. It is impossible to know, but I guess that the problem comes from pandas transformation of columns

Comment: could be your data contain duplicates.